# How to simplify WWW or No WWW in one elegant Apache Rewrite?

Tags: apache, http, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

Dear folks,
The `(www.)?` part in the below code doesnt work properly I feel:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mywebsite.com$
RewriteRule ^$ /de/home [L]
```

The above code now works together with this:

```
####  http:// >> http://www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

I feel it could be made simpler by extending the first code block sothat it captures both `http://` and `http://www.` towards /de/home

How do adapt the first code block sothat it is versatile and captures any version with or without www to load under water /de/home? Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second set of rule **is** the way to do it.

`%{HTTP_HOST}` does not contains `http://` part of the URL. Maybe you can use `%{THE_REQUEST}` but I don't see why use another syntax than the second block.

BTW, how much simpler than "if the host does not match www.-> then add www. to what the user typed" ??